# Is $\Bbb R^2 \subset P^2$ by isomorphism?

Tags: vector-space-isomorphism

According to page 10 of [Construction of Number Systems by Prof. Kumar](https://www.math.wustl.edu/%7Ekumar/courses/310-2009/peano.pdf), we define a map $f:\Bbb N \rightarrow \Bbb Z$ by $f(k)=[(a+k,a)]$ for some $a\in\Bbb N$. Then we show this function $f$ is one-to-one and $f(a+b)=f(a)\oplus f(b)$ and $f(ab)=f(a)\otimes f(b)$. Here $\oplus$ and $\otimes$ are addition and multiplication on $\Bbb Z$, as opposed to $+$ and $*$ on $\Bbb N$. Prof. Kumar writes that this implies $\Bbb N \subset \Bbb Z$.

I suppose this is because $f$ is an isomorphism from $\Bbb N$ to a subset of $\Bbb Z$. I have only a basic knowledge of isomorphisms from undergraduate linear algebra.

Following this reasoning, consider $\Bbb R^2$ and $P^1$ (the set of all polynomials degree 1 or less). $\Bbb R^2$ is isomorphic to $P^1$ by the function:
$f((a,b))=a+bx$. Since $P^1 \subset P^2$, does this mean that $\Bbb R^2 \subset P^2$?

Thank you for your help in advance.

EDIT: I am not familiar with abstract algebra, so I ask that you kindly explain any abstract algebra terms.

Comment: When you claim that two structures are isomorphic, you must precise completely the structures: are they rings? vector spaces?

Comment: Vector spaces, according to my linear algebra textbook. I haven't dealt with rings before.

Comment: The natural numbers do not form a group wrt addition and hence are not a group. However, they form a monoid. Indeed, $f$ is an isomorphism of monoids between $\mathbb{N}$ and $f(\mathbb{N})$. Thus we can identify $\mathbb{N}$ with $f(\mathbb{N})$ and claim (by abuse of notation) that $\mathbb{N}\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Similarly, $\Bbb R^2$ can be identified with a sub-vector space of $P^2.$